# Office Addin Custom Attributes on Range Text

Tags: vsto, office-interop, openxml, office-addins, office-automation

I would like to know if it's possible to add additional attributes to simple Range text or Paragraph text from my Word Add-in.  For simplicity see code below where I can populate the document with text but additionally i would like to store additional but behind the scenes info along with that text. Ultimately I want these read these custom attributes using the Open Xml SDK when these documents go through a processing stage.

```
private void AddAttributedContent(string documentContent)
        {
            var doc = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument);
            var range = doc.Range();
            range.Font.Size = 12;
            range.Font.Name = "Calibri";
            range.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
            range.Text = documentContent;
            // range.AddOpenXmlProperty("MyProp", "MyValue");

            var para = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
            para.Range.Text = documentContent;
            //para.AddCustomProperty("MyProp", "MyVal");

        }
```

Edit:

Ideally our property would sit inside of the resulting RunProprties :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You could probably do it with a content control or a text box though.

For a [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.contentcontrol_members(v=office.14).aspx), you could probably use [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.contentcontrol.tag(v=office.14).aspx) (if this is like sources, it probably has to be unique, though the description seems to imply it's meant for the purpose you need) or [Title](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.contentcontrol.title(v=office.14).aspx).

```
The Tag property is different from the Title property in that a tag is never displayed while a user edits a document. Instead, developers can use it to store a value for programmatic manipulation while the document is opened.
```

For a text box (a [Shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape_members(v=office.14).aspx)), you could use [AlternativeText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.alternativetext(v=office.14).aspx) or [Title](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.title(v=office.14).aspx).

Note that altering Title (in both cases) or AlternativeText will probably affect the way the document is displayed if you save it as HTML.

Comment: Word bookmarks also are a good option (using the bookmark name similar to the content control tag)

Comment: Chris, appreciate the quick response. We've looked at ContentControls and thus far they do not provide the visual look and their properties window does not contain enough formatting options. For example say I want something formatted as a decimal with a precision of 2. I thought the whole purpose of "Open XML" was that we could extend the solution to our needs? See screen shot of resulting Xml -- Ideally we would just add our stuff to the "RunProperties".  If this isn't possible, is it possible to change the aesthetics of ContentControl and override it's property dialog?

Comment: Hey Dirk, thanks.  We would like to store more attributes related to a piece of inline content. See screen shot I've attached.  This "RunProprerties" is perfect.  How can I write to it?

Comment: The purpose of Open XML afaik is that other applications can read/write it, as opposed to a binary format where the structure is not publicly defined. I don't think the structure is open to custom elements. You could add to the XML with generic XML manipulation, but Word would probably choke on it.

Comment: Word offers quite a bit of extensibility, but only in very specific ways. Dialogs like the properties for a content control, are not customizable at all. You could probably replace the dialog via a custom context menu item, but there's no guarantee that the formatting you want would actually work inside the control.